# you are using an unsupported command-line flag use fake ui for media stream

Tags: google-chrome

I'm getting this message consistently when opening a chrome plugin "eclinical works". This just started. I reinstalled the plugin/reset chrome to default with no success. Thought maybe it had to do with their cameras but they dont actually have cams on these particular computers. This is a clinic that I do IT support for and we have been using eclinical works for years and never saw this until now. They are using chrome version 98. Ive tried doing my own research on this but is difficult to dig down. Can anyone share an idea?

Answer (score 2):

The unsupported command-line flag warning can be suppressed by adding `--test-type` to the end of the command line.

This is per this older link, in the Chromium bug reports:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=376424

EClinicalWorks is trying to push everyone into a web-plugin based system, which was pretty obviously their original intent back in 2006.  Unfortunately, back then, there was no way for them to properly link devices such as scanners and ECG/EKG machines into a web browser.

So, you'll be seeing these growing pains for a while. The latest is a constant litany of having to grant permissions to the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

LOL, it's a bug that presented itself after a Chrome update.  eClinicalWorks does not have an ETA on when this will be addressed/fixed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).